# Embed Google Visualization API generated chart in Google Slide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-slides

I'm generating customized charts thanks to the Google Visualization chart API because the standards layouts offered by Sheets are not convenient for my need. These charts are generated thanks to a Google Apps Script deployed as a WebApp.
In addition of displaying live in my browser, I would like to arrange the generated charts in a Google Slide.
Do you know how I could embed generated charts through the Visualization API in the Google Slide (and refresh automatically when the slide is loaded) ?

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself and changed my mind. In addition of using Google Visualization API to generate the charts embedded in my WebApp, I developped another code to generate the static images.

Instead of using Visualization API, I went to Chart API, detailed here:
[Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts)

In a standard Google Apps Script, simply use this code to generate wanted charts:

```
function getChart() {

  var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'x')
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'act')
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'tgt')
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'mo')
    .addRow(['A', 90, 95, 150])
    .addRow(['B', 80, 95, 150])
    .addRow(['C', 100, 95, 150])
    .build();


  var chart = Charts.newBarChart()
    .setDataTable(data)
    .setRange(0, 150)
    .setTitle('My Chart')
    .setOption('series', {
      1: { lineWidth: 1, type: 'line'},
      2: { type: 'scatter'}
    })
    .setOption('legend', 'none')
    .setOption('chartArea', {'width': '80%', 'height': '100%'})
    .setColors(['#D9D9D9', '#0085AD'])
    .setOption('annotations', { textStyle: { color: '#000000' }})
    .build();


  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID');
  folder.createFile(chart.getAs('image/png')).setName('Image name');

}
```